# Remove time gaps for intraday plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, finance

I am struggling with a classic problem in Python (matplotlib) but I didn't find a proper answer after a long search. I am trying to plot intraday financial data for 2 different days. I have the data for the trading hours only and I would like to remove any gap between 2 different days. 
I like the way pandas is formatting my x axis and I would like to keep it.

Is it possible to have some help. I tried to turn the index to string and other things but nothing works.

[image: code + plot]

Comment: If you are trying to python it may be good to state that in more places than just the hashtags.